# Does "convert to edit" let moderators move comments?

Tags: support, editing, answers, comments, moderation

When moderators convert an answer to and edit--which deletes the answer and places its content at the end of the question--do they have the ability to move the comments from that answer to the question as well? Or are these always lost? I know that converting an answer to a comment allows its comments to be preserved; does converting it to an edit allow this, too? I'm asking because this will sometimes affect how I flag. I won't ask moderators to do this if they can't actually do it.

As some background (to non-moderators reading this), moderators can [convert an answer into a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74815/way-to-convert-an-answer-to-a-comment) on some other post. This is occasionally done to preserve content posted as an answer that doesn't attempt to answer the question but is [otherwise valuable](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). When doing so, they can either leave its own comment replies intact as additional comments on the same post. I don't know the specific details of how each is achieved, but I've seen both done. On the occasion that I raise a custom "in need of moderator intervention"  flag to ask that an answer that's been commented on be converted into a comment, I often specify whether or not I think its existing comment replies should be preserved.

Moderators can also [convert an answer into an *edit*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert-to-edit) on the question if the answer is posted by the OP. [Self-answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) are good, but sometimes an asker posts additional information about the problem that doesn't include a solution as an answer, when it ought to have been an edit.

[image: screenshot showing the convert to edit option for moderators]

<sup>**Screenshot copied from [Why was the “convert to edit” action disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195025/why-was-the-convert-to-edit-action-disabled) by [Mr.Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158428/mr-wizard) on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).**</sup>

I'm *not* suggesting that, if this can be done, then it ought to be done more often, nor even that the system should necessarily allow this. I'm just asking if the system *does* allow moderators to do this. I presume that doing so would sometimes intersperse comments on the post-made-edit with comments on the question and create confusion, so this ability would have to be used carefully.

The specific posts that motivated me to ask about this are [Where are my iptables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564993/where-are-my-iptables) and [its answer by the OP that should have been an edit](https://askubuntu.com/a/565051/22949) (which we've deleted but [can be seen here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925051215/https://askubuntu.com/questions/564993/where-are-my-iptables#565051)). I'm not totally sure that the comments on that answer *should* be placed on the question itself, but as I was thinking about it and considering raising a custom moderator flag, I realized I did not actually know if moderators have this ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the "Convert to Edit" button does not let us do anything with comments.